# Circle shaped notifications turns into 30px wide pill in different container

Tags: html, css

I have this side nav where there are notifications, and I have a problem that one notification circle is a circle, but one notification is a pill that is 30px wide. The css is almost the exact same between the two, the only difference is an absolute and static positioning, but I've changed the positioning and the problem still exists. Attached is a picture of the problem:
[image]

So obviously the one next to my name is correct and the one next to the selection "Notifications" is the one incorrect. Here is the CSS for the one near my name:

```
.notification {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: $main-red;
    min-width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 2px;
    left: 13px;
    top: 78px;

}
```

And here is the CSS for the one near the word "Notifications"

```
.notification {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: $main-red;
    min-width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 2px;
    left: 13px;
    top: 78px;

}

.notification.in-bar {
    position: static;
    margin-left: 5px;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
}
```

And here is the HTML for the picture:

```
<div class="profile">

    <div class="person">

        <div class="notification over-picture">0</div>
        <img src="/assets/icons/profile.svg" alt="A profile icon or picture" title="Profile" class="profile-picture">

        <div class="details">

            <span class="name"><?=$extra_html['full_name']?></span>
            <span class="status <?=$extra_html['current_status']['class']?>"><?=$extra_html['current_status']['title']?></span>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="options">

        <img src="/assets/icons/profile-more.svg" alt="A small icon with three dots" title="More" class="more">

        <div class="shadowbox">

            <span class="status-selection selection">Set Availability Status</span>

            <div class="available-options">

                <?php 
                    foreach($extra_html['status'] as $agent_status) {
                        echo "<span class='selection $agent_status[class]' onclick='changeCurrentAgentStatus(`$agent_status[title]`, `$agent_status[class]`)'>$agent_status[title]</span>";
                    }
                ?>

            </div>

            <hr>

            <div class="status-selection selection">Notifications <span class="notification in-bar">0</span></div>

            <hr>

            <a class="selection" title="Go to your Account Preferences, <?=$extra_html[first_name]?>" href="/preferences/">Account Preferences</a>
            <a class="selection" title="Log out" href="/logout/">Log Out</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

What is the difference that is extending the notification out like a pill?

Answer (score 1):

In your class ,just add a property,

```
.notification {
 width:14px;
}
```

PS: I dont see the use of 'min-width'. So you can just replace it with width.